# Login flow with ExNavigator and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm working a React Native app using ExNavigator and I want to use Redux. I want a basic login flow, by which I mean:

1. User clicks "Log in" with correct info
2. Redux does a usual async flow through redux-thunk or something
3. When the user is logged in/request was successful, move to Profile route

I've done Redux login in the web, but I am sort of confused as to how to move ExNavigator to the Profile route when the login works because the Navigator object seems to be contained completely in the components and not Redux.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I use often is detecting state changes in my component's `componentWillReceiveProps`, and triggering the navigation transition from there.

Let's say your state contains a property `isLoggedIn`, which you set to `true` when the login is successful. The property is also passed as a prop to your component. You can then:

```
componenWillReceiveProps({isLoggedIn}) {
  if (isLoggedIn && !this.props.isLoggedIn) {
    this.props.navigator.push(nextRoute());
  }
}
```

This might not be the most elegant way of solving the problem, but it works. The React Native `Navigator`, and consequently `ExNavigator` built on top of it, does not lend it self easily to the Redux architecture.

React Native team is working on a new navigation API, currently known as `NavigationExperimental`, which ships with latest versions of RN. It works nicely with Redux ([example](https://github.com/jlyman/RN-NavigationExperimental-Redux-Example)), but as its name indicate, it's still very much experimental.